# Using Autosizing is causing my items to shift wrongly 20 pixels to the left

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, autorotate

I am designing a table with custom cells layout. To do the custom cell layout I added an empty nib file, then added a Table View Cell, and then designed everything based on my needs. After that I load my custom nib in the Table View using `loadNibNamed` inside the function `cellForRowAtIndexPath`... Everything is ok and the custom table is exactly as I want.

Now I want to enable rotations so when the user rotates the device the design rotates as well. My custom cell is made of labels and images therefore the simplest way to handle view rotations is by using the **Autosizing** property from **Interface Builder**. And here is the problem: when I select the appropriate Autosizing combination for an element in my custom cell, the final result on run time will be shifted by 20 pixels to the left. So rotation works but everything is wrongly shifted. Here is a visual interpretation of my problem:

I select Autosizing like this:

[image]

And the result is identical to where I place my label (This Week) like this:

[image]

Now I select the appropriate Autosizing for my label:

[image]

But the result is wrongly shifted by 20 pixels to the left like this:

[image]

You can see that the label "This Week" is not on top of the DisclosureIndicator as in the previous image. The wrong shifting is in all device orientations, not only in portrait. What I am doing wrong? Shouldn't Autosizing preserve the original size and location of my objects on the view?

Comment: Does the label show up 20 pixels to the left in IB?  Have you tried adjusting your X value by 20 pixels?

Comment: this is because the label belongs to the contentView of the cell. The disclosure indicator makes this area smaller. You can see it when you set a background color, e.g. `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];`

Comment: @Alan Moore, On IB the label looks exactly where I want it to be. In fact playing with the Autosizing properties is not changing the position of the label in IB. The problem only appears on run time. If I displace the label by 20 pixels it will appear wrong in IB but correct in run time but this cause me another problem in another label where I wanted to change it width not its position, and it was not growing to the full width, it is also smaller by a certain offset.

Comment: @phix23 yes you're right :) I tried to set the accessory type to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` and the problem did not occur. But I need in my design to have the `DisclosureIndicator` so what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Well thanks guys, I fixed my problem based your comments. Since the DisclosureIndicator is eating from my sizes, I used a yellow background on every affected label and added 20 pixels manually either to the width or to the X position, and it solved the case. Thank you both :)